# Can the ng-model value be changed from another element's event - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to change the selected value of dropdown when user clicks on the anchor tags. Is it possible.

Something like

```
<a href ng-click="{SelectedPage=SelectedPage-1}">Prev</a>
<select ng-model="SelectedPage">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<a href ng-click="{SelectedPage=SelectedPage+1}">Next</a>
```

For example, when the value selected in dropdown is 2, and user clicks on `Next`, the selection in dropdown changes to 3 & also `$scope.SelectedPage` becomes 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Just use

```
<a href ng-click="SelectedPage=SelectedPage-1">Prev</a>
```

and

```
<a href ng-click="SelectedPage=SelectedPage+1">Next</a>
```

Without `{` & `}`
You should use `ng-href` instead of `href`. See [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)